# Is there an attribute like `#![windows_subsystem(windows)]` for macOS?

Tags: macos, rust

According to [this release note](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/06/08/Rust-1.18.html), there is a new `#![windows_subsystem(windows)]` attribute that does not display a console when running a windowed application. It works on Windows and everything is fine.

I don't know what to do to make it work for macOS too. When I launch my app on macOS, it displays a console. Is there a way to hide the console even for a Mac application?

Comment: MacOS doesn't usually display a console at all. How are you launching the application?

Comment: double click from finder on the file generated by `cargo build --release`. Mac info says it's a `Unix executable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cargo builds Unix-style executable.

In order to not open the terminal on launch, you have to create an OSX application wrapper, a.k.a [bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1). You could use [cargo-bundle](https://github.com/burtonageo/cargo-bundle) for this need.